# Proving: $n \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - m_x)^2 \leq n\|x\|^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra

I have a bilinear form:

$$
f(x,x) = n \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - m_x)^2
$$

Where: 
$$
n \in N, x \in R^n, m_x = \frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_n}{n}
$$

I want to show that

$$
0 \leq f(x,x) \leq n\|x\|^2
$$

The left side is ok since we have a multiplication of $n \in \Bbb N$ and a square value we surely get:

$$
0 \leq f(x,x)
$$

But I don't know how to prove: 
$$
f(x,x) \leq n\|x\|^2
$$

I want to say something like: 
$$
n \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - m_x)^2 \leq n \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i)^2 = n\|x\|^2
$$

Therefore 
$$
f(x,x) \leq n\|x\|^2
$$

But I don't know how to justifye it.

By playing with the function I also got to this:

$$
f(x,x) = (n-1)\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_iy_i - \sum_{i \neq j}x_iy_j
$$

Can someone give a hint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me write $m_x=\mathsf E(x)$. Then $$\frac{f(x,x)}n=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(x_i^2 -2x_i \mathsf E(x)+\mathsf E(x)^2\right)=\|x\|_2^2-2n\mathsf E(x)^2+n\mathsf E(x)^2=\|x\|_2^2-n\mathsf E(x)^2\le\|x\|_2^2$$

More generally, if $X\in L^2(\Omega)$ is a random variable, then $$\|X-\mathsf E(X)\|_{L^2}\le\|X\|_{L^2}.$$

Comment: Now i see, the key is the $2nE(x) \Rightarrow nE(x)^2$ and i think i understand, each $x_i$ became $x_i^2$ and the demonator stays the same, hence the multiplication by $2$, thank you for the help.

Comment: Correction: I get for the $m_x$ that is multiplyed by its nominator, therefore the square. thanks

Comment: @Alon the idea is this: $$\sum_{i=1}^n 2 x_i \mathsf E(x) =  2\mathsf E(x)\cdot \color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}=2\mathsf E(x)\cdot\color{blue}{n \mathsf E(x)}$$

Answer (score 1):

A first way to do it is to remark that the fonction $f(c)=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-c)^2$ goes to $\infty$ when $|c|\to\infty$ and is $C^1$, so that its minimum is reached when its derivative is $0$, which is the point $c = m_x$.

Therefore, $f(c)≤ f(0)$, which is exactly your inequality. The other way was just posted by Maximilian Janisch.